# creating class instances from a text file in python

Tags: python, file, instances

I have a polynomial class:

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, *termpairs):
        self.termdict = dict(termpairs)
```

To add an instance to this class, you enter the following:

```
P = Polynomial((3,2), (4,5), (9,8))
```

Now I'm trying to create a function that reads information from a text file, and from that text file, it creates an instance of the Polynomial class. The information is stored in the text file like this:

```
4 6
2 3
9 8
3 5
0 42
```

So far, the function looks like this:

```
def read_file(polyfilename):
    polyfilename = open("polyfilename.txt", "r")
    poly1 = polyfilename.read()
    polyfilename.close()
    poly1 = [line.split() for line in poly1.split("\n")]
    poly1 = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in poly1]
    for item in poly1:
        return Polynomial(item)
```

It only creates a Polynomial instance for the first pair in the text file, how can I make a Polynomial instance for all of the pairings in the text file?

EDIT:
I now have this as my function:

```
def read_file(polyfilename):
    polyfilename = open("polyfilename.txt", "r")
    poly = polyfilename.read()
    polyfilename.close()
    poly = [line.split() for line in poly.split("\n")]
    poly = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in poly]
    return Polynomial(poly[0], poly[1], poly[2], poly[3], poly[4])
```

It gives me the answer I'm looking for, however, the length of these text files can vary, so typing poly[1], poly[2] won't work. Is there a way I can go through each index no matter what the length is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
return Polynomial(*poly)
```

instead of

```
return Polynomial(poly[0], poly[1], poly[2], poly[3], poly[4])
```

Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) ... read the paragraph starting with """If the syntax *expression appears in the function call"""

Bonus: Your function doesn't use its arg, reuses the name `poly` like crazy, and isn't idiomatic, so I rewrote the whole thing:

```
def read_file(polyfilename):
    with open(polyfilename) as f:
        return Polynomial(*[[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f])
```

HTH

Comment: lol, I didn't even think to use *poly, also, thanks for the tips for making the function look a little neater.

Answer (score 1):

return always exits the function immediately upon calling and can only return one item.  So if you want multiple items (in a sense) to be returned, you must pack them in a list, then return that.

In place of the for loop:

```
polys = []
for item in poly1:
    polys.append(Polynomial(item))
return polys
```

You will of course have to deal with this new result as a list.

Comment: This helped, I'll try to figure out what to do with the list.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, it looks like this is returning after the first one is created, so you only get one back. Try replace the `return` statement with a `yield` then:

```
for p in read_file('somefile'):
  # p is a polynomial object, do what you will with it
```

In case it helps [the first response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) is a good summary of yield. Again this is just from a quick look at what you've written.

```
    def read_file(polyfilename):
        polyfilename = open(polyfilename, "r")
        poly1 = polyfilename.read()
        polyfilename.close()
        poly1 = [line.split() for line in poly1.split("\n")]
        poly1 = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in poly1]
        for item in poly1:
            yield Polynomial(item)

    for p in read_file('sample.txt'):
        print p
```

Produces

```
<__main__.Polynomial instance at 0x39f3f0>
<__main__.Polynomial instance at 0x39f418>
<__main__.Polynomial instance at 0x39f3f0>
<__main__.Polynomial instance at 0x39f418>
<__main__.Polynomial instance at 0x39f3f0>
```