# Python - create and access an arbitrary number of instances from a list or file input

Tags: python, list, dynamic, instances

So there's a [few partial answers to this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291778/creating-class-instances-from-a-text-file-in-python), but nothing clearly answers this question.

I want to take a .txt file with an arbitrary number of names, each on a new line, like this.

```
John Citizen
Genghis Khan
Ex Parrot
... could be hundreds of names
```

Then I want to create a new instance of this Friend() object

```
class Friend(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.somequality = "somequality"

    def somemethod(self):
        return self.somequality
```

for **each line** in the text file.

---

Currently I have this code:

```
friends_dict = {}
with open('NameList.txt') as f:
    friend_list = [line.strip() for line in f]
friend_instance_list = []
for i in friend_list:
    friend_instance_list.append(Friend(i))
friends_dict = dict(zip(friend_list, friend_instance_list))
```

And this works, it makes a dictionary of instances, paired with the strings they represent. I can even call their names like this:

```
print(friends_dict["John Citizen"].name)
```

---

Is this actually the best way to do things? It seems really clumsy and annoying not to have any of these objects assigned to variables. It makes dealing with them a real pain, but I don't have any idea how to go about assigning these instances from the dictionary to variables.

Comment: When I run exactly this code, it works—`thevariable` gets the value `'somequality'`, just as you'd want it to. So, are you sure this is the same as your actual code?

Comment: As a side note, the same way you did `friend_list = [line.strip() for line in f]`, you can do `friend_instance_list = [Friend(i) for i in friend_list]`. Or, even better, just go right to `friends_dict = {i: Friend(i) for i in friend_list}` and don't even bother with the `friend_instance_list`.

Comment: Meanwhile: Your link was broken. I guessed that you meant the first page that comes up when you search SO for that text, rather than the text itself interpreted as a URL, but you might want to check to make sure I got it right. More importantly: in what way are those answers "partial"? What part of the question do they not answer?

Comment: It's working for me too, the only way it wouldnt work is if 'def somemethod' is not idented/defined correctly

Comment: I've edited this question because I found the answer to my problem (it was stupid, related to trying to save the dictionary using pickle).

Comment: have you tried `friends_dict[u'John Citizen']`? Maybe it's a charset issue...